# android:state_pressed is not working

Tags: android, resources, android-selector

I have the following XML code in `res/drawable` and I set button `background` to this `drawable`. However when I pressed the button it is not not changing the `color`. Thanks for help

```
<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent">
</item>

<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary">
</item>

<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/black">
</item>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <selector>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#EDCFE9"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="#EDCFE9"/>
    <item android:drawable="#603F86"/>
    </selector>
```

This will change the button color on button press.

Order matters when specifying the selector fields - whichever selector it matches first, going from top to bottom, will be the one displayed. The default button state should always be specified last.

Answer (score 8):

well you need to remember that android read line after line and returnthe first true statment.
because you have enable false / true items BEFORE the state_Selected it will always choose enabled = false / true item.
simply move your bottum code before the "state_enabled" like so:

```html
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/black">
</item>

<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent">
</item>

<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary">
</item>
```

Comment: That is the best answer.

Comment: this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new drawable with below code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pink"/> <!-- pressed state -->
<item android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- default state -->
</selector>
```

Add the below colors into `values > colors.xml` file

```
<color name="blue">#49B8C7</color>
<color name="pink">#FF8EB9</color>
```